# Widget with remote images

Tags: android, image, widget

I´m trying to assign an image of type "BitmapDrawable" to a widget.
The image comes from the Internet and convert it to "BitmapDrawable".

```
Bitmap.createBitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap (bmWidget1, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
bmdWidget1 = new BitmapDrawable (resizedBitmap);
```

The problem is that I do not know how to put that image in the widget programmatically

I am using

```
Buttons = new RemoteViews RemoteViews (context.getPackageName (), R.layout.mywidget);
buttons.setImageViewBitmap (R.id.imageWidget1, WidgetConfig.bmdWidget1);
```

But I always suggest modifications that do not work (change to bitmap, change to setImageViewResource)

If someone can ayudarem with a code example will be very grateful.

thank you very much